# Запрос в Linq C#

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Добрый день !

Имеется `array` в котором записаны `CheckBox`. Некоторые из них `isChecked`, некоторые `!isChecked`.

Мне нужно выбрать все `checkbox`, которые `isChecked` и удалить из этого array все checkBox у которых `.Tag == "равен чему либо".`

Я пробовал вот так:

```
    var myTestArray = _statusCheckBoxes.Where(x => !x.Tag.Equals("New") && !x.Tag.Equals("Active") && !x.Tag.Equals("Activating")); 
// тут я хотел выбрать все чексбоксы кроме тех, у которых .Tag равен (New, Active, Activating) 
     var xxx = myTestArray.Where(x => x.IsChecked); 
// тут я выбрал из тех, которые мне нужны isSelected
```

Но мой запрос выборки нужных элементов не работает.
Подскажите как это можно сделать или что мне нужно изменить в данном коде ?

Спасибо !

**UPD.**

```
private void checkTestMethod()
{
    var myxxx =
        _statusCheckBoxes.Where(
            x => (x.Tag as string) != "New" && (x.Tag as string) != "Active" && (x.Tag as string) != "Activating");

    var xxx = myxxx.Where(x => x.IsChecked);

    foreach (var item in xxx)
    {
        if (item.IsChecked)
            MessageBox.Show("Bla bla bla");
    }
}
```

Comment: @Raider указал на ошибку, удалил ответ. Думаю дальше.

Comment: А что выдаст вот это? http://pastebin.com/ZBDstBrF

Comment: @VladD в этой переменной все .Tags из моего массива

Comment: Ну да, а можно скопипастить куда-нибудь на pastebin конкретное значение?

Comment: Я очень не понимаю этого:
(itm.Tag as string) != "New" <- .Tag сейчас имеет в себе "New" но компилятор говорит, что условие имеет true, хотя должен быть по идее false

Comment: Хм. Может, где-то затесались русские буквы? Например, `е`?

Comment: @VladD русские буквы - исключено. http://pastebin.com/AmGBWfTb

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52320/discussion-between-kxxko-and-vladd).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Старый ответ удалён, новый ответ:

---

Расследование в комментариях и в чате показало, что объекты в `Tag` имели тип не `string`. Поэтому для сравнения нужен был такой код:

```
x.Tag.ToString() != "New"
```

и т. д. Кроме того, проверки можно объединить:

```
.Where(x => x.IsChecked &&
            x.Tag.ToString() != "New" &&
            x.Tag.ToString() != "Active" &&
            x.Tag.ToString() != "Activating")
```

Если `Tag` может быть равным `null`, то нужен ещё вопросительный знак:

```
(x.Tag?.ToString()) != "New"
```

и т. д.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ !
Сделал так, как Вы и сказали, но это все равно возвращает все элементы =(

Comment: @kxxko: Хм, странно, должно работать. А можете показать больше кода? Может, ещё где-то есть проблема?

Comment: @kxxko: Что вы дальше делаете с `xxx`?

Comment: прогоняю foreach и делаю свои проверки на каждом элементе. Мне тоже казалось, что будет работать.

Comment: Должно работать. А покажите всё же код.

Comment: Добавил код в вопрос !

Comment: @VladD Вы путаете `object.Equals` и `object.ReferenceEquals`. Метод `Equals` у строки переопределен, и он выполнит сравнение по значению, а не по ссылке.

Comment: @Raider: Хм, вы правы :-(